# JS / Return - [object Object] при выводе текста

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Скрипт:

```js
    $('a.holdOnStart').mouseenter(function () {
        var text = $('a.holdOnStart');
        var count = text.length;
        var randomizer = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        for ( var i=0; i < count; i++ ) {
            text += randomizer.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * randomizer.length));
            return $(this).text(text);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="holdOnStart">Link</a>
```

При наведении возвращает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём кроется ошибка, не могу найти в интернетах решение. Спасибо!

Comment: В чем задача то? `$('a.holdOnStart')` - объект, к нему конкатенируется рандомный символ `randomizer.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * randomizer.length))` ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev, Задача рандомизировать текст при ховере и вернуть в исходное состояние когда мышь не на объекте, вывести без типа объекта

Comment: Что значит "рандомизировать текст"? Вы явно пытаетесь что-то сделать с jQuery объектом присоединив к нему символ из строки .... это не целиком рандом явно должен быть

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a.holdOnStart').mouseenter(function() {
  var text = $(this).text(); // Можно так, элемент который создал событие
  
  var randomizer = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  if(/\?/.test(text)){ // Delimiter ?
    text = text.replace(/(\?.*)$/, '');
  }
  // After cutting the length of the previous randomly added string
  var count = text.length;
  
  text += '?'; // Adding delimiter, can be changed
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    text += randomizer.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * randomizer.length));

  }
  
  $(this).text(text); // Нужно так, устанавливать текст в линк
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="holdOnStart">Link and other</a>
```